# How to convert integer into date using Apache Spark / Python on Databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, epoch

Relatively simple question I feel. Attempting to convert an integer column into epoch time (MM/DD/YYY)?

e.g., convert 881250949 --> 12/04/1997

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using from_unixtime and date_format function, we can achieve the required result:

**SPARK_SCALA**

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  // Sample dataframe
  val df = Seq(881250949).toDF("col")

  df.withColumn("col", date_format(from_unixtime('col), "MM/dd/yyyy"))
    .show(false)

+----------+
|col       |
+----------+
|12/04/1997|
+----------+
```

**PYSPARK**

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

# Sample dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,881250949)], "id int, date int")

df.withColumn("date", date_format(from_unixtime("date"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))\
    .show()
/*
+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  1|12/04/1997|
+---+----------+
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Mohana. I think there is something wrong with the syntax in the response you provided. Believe there should be an ' after col

Comment: Sorry didn't check on which language you asked the code. In scala that syntax works. In python you should wrap column name with in single/double quotes.

Comment: I keep getting an error that 'from_unixtime' is not defined. Any ideas how to explicitly define it?

Comment: Edited the post, added pyspark code. Please have a look.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I realize that I simply had to do the following:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
F.date_format(F.from_unixtime("date"), "MM/dd/yyyy")).show()